# Why we use in & in mysql query condition?

Tags: mysql

One of guys share me a query but still i am not undestand what is mean. Any one have idea why we use "&" in mysql query.

It also return result but don't know what condition is applying.

Comment: As William Shakespeare [wrote](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/much_ado/much_ado.5.1.html), _"this learned constable is too cunning to be understood."_ If your colleague has written code that is so hard to understand, then it's not good code. Both the intention and the function of the code should be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [bitwise logical AND operator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

The operator `&` is the [bitwise AND](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and) operator for MySql.

> ...why we are use "&" in for condition

Your question is application specific and can't be answered without knowing the requirement.

The binary representation of `30` is `00011110`.
As you can see this number has the bits 2 to 5 (starting from right) set (=1).
Any integer number, like `entity_id`, when written in binary, that has any of these bits set when used in the operation `entity_id & 30` would return a non-zero value.

For example when `entity_id = 12`, then `entity_id` in binary is `00001100` and:

```
00001100(=12) & 00011110(=30) = 00001100(=12)
```

which is non-zero value interpreted as `TRUE` in the `WHERE` clause.

But when `entity_id = 129`, then `entity_id` in binary is `10000001` and:

```
10000001(=129) & 00011110(=30) = 00000000(=0)
```

which is `0` and it is interpreted as `FALSE` in the `WHERE` clause.

So, `entity_id = 12` will be returned by the query but `entity_id = 129` will be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is [bitwise and operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and)

please be aware that this condition is **terribly** wrong when you're looking for exact 30 for id, for example it will match 62 and 2, 4, 6, ... also (any integer that has common `1` in the 5 least-significant digits with `11110` (`30` in binary) in it's binary form)